# ASP.NET Core MSB4018 in new project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I get an error immediately after creating a new project (only ASP.NET MVC, other types work fine). I tried to rebuild project and solution but it didnt help. Here is an error:

```
Error MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageAssets" task failed unexpectedly.
NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find fallback package folder 'D:\VS\VS SDK \NuGetPackages'.
at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePathResolver..ctor(String userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(IEnumerable`1 packageFolders)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.NuGetPackageResolver.CreateResolver(LockFile lockFile)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheWriter..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader.CreateReaderFromDisk(ResolvePackageAssets task, Byte[] settingsHash)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.CacheReader..ctor(ResolvePackageAssets task)
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ReadItemGroups()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePackageAssets.ExecuteCore()
at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() study C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.203\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 241
```

Comment: Do you have a nuget.config file with `D:\VS\VS SDK \NuGetPackages` in it? The error suggests that path doesn't exist.

Comment: @DaveShaw , I have a folder, but there is no nuget.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case deletion and reinstallation of VS solved this problem.